# Connected Components are Closed

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am trying to prove that if $C$ is a connected component of $X$, then $C$ is closed. Here is my attempt:

Let $C$ be a connected component of $X$. Then $\overline{C} \supseteq C$ must be connected as well, and since every connected subspace intersects one, and only one, connected component (and is therefore contained in it), it follows that $\overline{C} \subseteq C$.

Is this right? Something about it is fishy...

Comment: $\overline{C}$ is always connected when $C$ is:  this is a standard result (you can even insert an intermediate subset).  Could $\overline{C}$ be any different from $C$?

Comment: Recall the definition of closed: A is closed if A^c is open.

Comment: @Randall To answer your question, no and that's what I thought I was showing. Isn't it true that a connected subspace intersects one, and only one, component; and does $C \subseteq \overline{C}$ imply that they intersect? From what I understand, this should immediately imply $\overline{C} \subseteq C$, since the components are equivalence classes.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.

Comment: Unless you belong to the church that declares $\varnothing$ to be disconnected, there is _one_ connected subspace that doesn't intersect any component. From the connectedness of $\overline{C}$, the equality $C = \overline{C}$ follows since components are by definition the _maximal_ connected subspaces.

Comment: The empty set is not disconnected. It's just not connected. This post was made by the intuitionist gang.

Answer (score 13):

A component of $x$ is the largest connected set containing $x$.

Let $C$ be a component of $x$.  Thus $x\in\overline{C}$ and $C \subseteq \overline{C}$.

However, $C$ is the largest connected set, therefore $\overline{C} \subseteq C$.
Hence $C = \overline{C}$, and $C$ is closed.

Answer (score 11):

Your proof is about right.
I'd formulate it as follows: a connected component $C$ of $X$ is a maximally connected subset; this means 2 things:

1. $C$ is connected.
2. if $C \subseteq D$ and $D$ is connected, $C=D$.

Now use that $C$ connected implies $\overline{C}$ connected.
Then applying 2. and noting that obviously $C \subseteq \overline{C}$, we conclude that $C = \overline{C}$, which is equivalent to $C$ being closed. QED.