# Is connected component open?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, locally-connected

There is a theorem that:A space is locally connected iff each connected components of an open set is open.

But recently I had seen to prove That each connected component is closed. [Connected Components are Closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486461/connected-components-are-closed)

Then how can the connected component of an open set be open if it is a locally connected space ? It will be contradiction to the statement that connected components is closed.

Comment: Think about $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.  What are the connected components?

Comment: In fact, it is true in general that any connected component is clopen (it is both open and closed). If you want a proof, you should add your definition of a "connected component" first.

Comment: sets are not doors, they can be open and closed at the same time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subset being closed doesn't preclude that subset from being open.  For a simple example, every [discrete space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) is locally connected, and every subset of a discrete space—in particular the singleton sets (which are the connected components)—is both open and closed.